# How can I install OS X on my AMD laptop?

Tags: macos

I have hi-end AMD laptop and I want some links about installation of latest OS X OS to it.

Is it possible to install OS X to AMD computer?

P.S. It's legal in my country (laws have priority over EULA). Performance of my laptop is much better, than performance of top Macbook Pro, so I don't want to change it.

Comment: Even if it's legal in your country, stack exchange has laws they need to follow to protect themselves. I remember there was a decision made about this type of question, but I can't remember what it was. I'm not voting to close as off topic because I don't remember the decision

Comment: @CanadianLuke I don't require direct links to hackintosh DVDs or another illegal content (such DVDs are illegal in my country too).